# How to extract schema id from confluent serialized avro payload in Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, confluent-schema-registry

I understand that avro serialized data has the 0 byte as magic byte and bytes 1-4 have the schema ID. This is a very important requirement for me but I'm not able to extract the schema id out using spark functions.

Can someone help me out with the equivalent code in scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From plain Scala KafkaConsumer, you'd use ByteArrayDesrializer in the consumer config, build a ByteBuffer from the consumed value, then call `get` (to discard the magic byte) and then `getInt` to fetch the ID. But that's not necessary in Spark; Spark always returns binary types for Kafka Dataframes and doesn't accept custom Kafka deserializer classes.

Refer [this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/consume-avro-data-from-kafka-topics-and-secured-schema-registry-with-databricks-confluent-cloud-on-azure/#step-7) on using `substring()` function on byte array to get the ID , and further how to actually use that with the Registry

Example in PySpark

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

binary_to_string = fn.udf(lambda x: str(int.from_bytes(x, byteorder='big')), StringType())

kafka_df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
  ...
  .withColumn('valueSchemaId', binary_to_string(fn.expr("substring(value, 2, 4)")))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to convert it to spark scala and it won't work, there is a blog or docs about it in spark scala as well?

Comment: @Tal You can see here how to define a UDF in Scala. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html Maybe also `Byte.toInt` function, or use `ByteBuffer` for the same...

Comment: Otherwise, what is wrong with using `substring(value, 2, 4)`? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#string-functions